# What does "mount -e <device>" do?

Tags: mount, options, qnx

**TL;DR**: What does `mount -e <device>` do?

### Overview

Over ssh, `mount` commands are being sent by software that I need to maintain. Twice, the mount commands use an `-e` option. I don't know what `-e` is for and can't find a good enough answer.

### Details

In my case, the procedure that is doing this is named "Verify Backup OS" and the command being sent over ssh is the following:

```
mount -e /dev/hd0; umount -f /dev/hd0t177.1; mount -e /dev/hd0; mount -tqnx6 /dev/hd0t177.1 /BackupPartition
```

After doing that, the software then appears to do a search in /BackupPartition so I think that's where the "verify" part of the procedure name comes into play.

### Man output

If I do `man mount`, the text for the command and for `-e` is:

```
Usage: mount [-abwruv] -t type [-o options] [special] mntpoint
   mount [-abwruv] -T type [-o options] special [mntpoint]
   mount [-abwruv] -e [-t|T type] [-o options] special [mntpoint]
   mount

   …

   -e Enumerate the device given by special
```

### Product Documentation

On [the QNX page for mount](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fm%2Fmount.html), it has `-e Enumerate the children of the special device.`

By the description it would appear that the `mount -e` somehow enumerates the device in some capacity. I was expecting that to mean "prints out some data to stdout", but that doesn't make much sense in this case since the output is not visible to the software user and is not piped or redirected anywhere, and I tried the command manually on the command line where it produced no output and no sign that anything happened.

**What does `mount -e <device>` do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also read the examples on qnx man mount?

> mount -e
>
> This will re-read the disk partition table for /dev/hd0, and create,
> update or delete /dev/hd0tXX block-special files for each partition.

With your ssh command it makes sense. I understand not much.

Comment: Thank you! No, I had not noticed that further explanation lower down.